# $(T/F)$ For a given matrix $A,$ the null space and the column space of $A$ are two subspaces of the same vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Was asked this in Linear Algebra. I think it's false but can't exactly explain why. Do they count as two different subspaces or are they complements? Also, what does it mean for two subspaces to be in the same vector space?

Comment: related: see rank-nullity theorem

Comment: The claim is generally false. E.g. if your matrix (with real entries) has 2 rows an 3 columns, its null space will be a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ and its column space  a subspace of $\Bbb R^2.$ And one cannot "construct" the sum of a vector of  $\Bbb R^3$ and a vector of  $\Bbb R^2.$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I think you meant compl**e**ments